# How to remove Grub Loader Screen (pop ups durin each boot!)

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

I haven't installed any multiple or dual os setup in my PC, hence I'm using Ubuntu LTS 18.04 as my main machine.

I'm very new to Linux community, so I've been experimenting with several distros like Elementary, Mint, Neon so far.

But now I've completely wiped off (FORMATTED) in order to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu but it's still showing me a list of Linux OS / even old Windows 7 list at every boot time. It seems a little annoying to look at those broken links.

So, please anyone help me to get rid of those list and disable BOOT GRUB LOADER.

I'm eager to learn something new in linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is no Linux issue, but results from UEFI. The UEFI boot record on your disk remembers the old boot information. Go to your BIOS and check the settings – there must be a section where you can disable all the old entries.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you could do:

- Boot into a windows installation media, for example from an USB. So
  insert the USB which have windows installer flashed on it and boot
  the PC up from this USB. You can flash windows on a USB by
  downloading the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft.
- When you have booted from the USB, press Shift + F10 to open CMD.
- Type "Diskpart".
- Type "List vol"
- Select the system volume by typing the system volume number. So if the system volume is 3, type "sel vol 3".
- Type "Assign letter k".
- Type "Exit" to exit diskpart.
- Type "k:" (remember the colon) to enter the directory we just assigned the letter to.
- Type "dir" and you should see a dir called EFI, now type "cd EFI", then type "dir" again.
- You should now see a dir called Ubuntu, now type "rmdir /S ubuntu" to remove ubuntu. Ubuntu should now be removed and windows should load now, but first we will remove the assigned letter.
- Type "diskpart" again, then "list vol", then select the vol which we assigned the letter to, i.e. the system volume, for example "sel vol 3", then type "remove letter k".
- Done, try rebooting, Ubuntu should be gone from boot now.

To check what operating systems you have installed, you can boot into BIOS and see the boot order, if Ubuntu is still there, you have not uninstalled Ubuntu or the above did not work.